# Do I have to create and use my own jquery script for slideToggle animation when using bootstrap offline (via npm)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I just learned to create a website using bootstrap. I created a project using bootstrap for the appearance of the website. Initially, I used an online bootstrap to make the website display work optimally. I made a navbar with the hamburger menu, and when I clicked it the result was like this:

[image: Animated hamburger menu]

There is a smooth animation when I click the hamburger menu.

Then I tested the appearance of my website using offline bootstrap, and the results were like this:

[image: Non-animated hamburger menu]

There is no animation when I click the hamburger menu.

When I try to use the jquery slideToggle() script in html (I put it in html just for testing), the animation will appear like I am using an online bootstrap.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#hamburgerMenu").click(function () {
           $("#navbarTogglerDemo02").slideToggle();
     });

});
</script>
```

Question: do I really have to implement the jquery slideToggle() script above into my javascript file or is there another way so I don't have to put the script? Because in online bootstrap I don't need to write the above script in my javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that I can think of that the offline bootstrap should behave any differently than the online one.

I'd be curious on where did you source the two files and i'd do a comparison between the two. If it's working online, all you're doing is getting that code and minifying it for local use like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: i have put that script, and i have put 
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script> too

but the animation doesn't work. 

When i put 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#hamburgerMenu").click(function () {
           $("#navbarTogglerDemo02").slideToggle();
     });

});
</script>

it's worked

Comment: Hmm. In that case, i'd say you need to implement the jquery script. At least it's a small enough script in this case.

Comment: Okay, i will implement it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The question has been answered, although I can't solve the error.

It turns out that the online bootstrap version that I am using is version 4.0.0 (I adjusted jquery and popper.js according to the documentation) and the offline version is 4.5.2. When I tried to use online bootstrap version 4.5.2 (with jquery and popper.js which have also been adjusted), the animation also didn't work. Once I tried bootstrap version 4.0.0 offline, the animation ran normally.

I'm not sure with this answer. There may be a bug in the bootstrap. But when I tried various methods, the result was same

Result:

- Bootstrap 4.0.0: animation in toggle both offline and online goes as desired (there is a smooth animation)
- Bootstrap 4.5.2: animation in toggle both offline and online does not work as desired (no animation)